# Android API levels functionality

Tags: android, api

Is it possible to achieve the same effect of any hardware independent functionality from the higher API levels in Android OS using the lowest or one of the lowest levels by default?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [compatibility library](http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html) allows older API levels to have access to some newer platform functionality.